# Use different styles for a component on different routes? Hide and Show data according to routes

Tags: css, reactjs, routes, react-redux

In Front page, I have a component called as land-card, in that card I've to show Heading, Image and 2 icons. But in another route(/marketplace), I need to show same component but it needs to have a bigger width, and have one extra icon and text. So how can I add conditions on render like which page will take which parts of that reducer data?

I've already tried using Routing condition from previous questions, but it did not worked.

````
      name: 'Plaza',
      months: '4',
      num: '1',
      x: '20',
      y: '-30',
      green: true,
      blue: true,
      manaSymbol: true,
      mana: '20,000',
    },```

This is the reducer file for that card data. I only need to show everything other than manaSymbol and mana on first page which already works, but without creating new component how can I make it show manaSymbol and mana on (/marketplace)?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a className with props for the first route eg. "card-style1" and for the second route "card-style2" and in the component you can write

(this.) only if it is a class component in case of function component only props.PROPNAME